# Prevent Clutter transition from getting stopped

Tags: c, gnome, vala, clutter

i'm using clutter transition to animate stuff:

```
actor.save_easing_state();
actor.set_easing_duration(1000);
//animate stuff
actor.restore_easing_state();
```

have read somewhere that if you start a new transition and another transition is already running the new transition will override the end values of the already running transition. how can i prevent this?

how can i make the current transition continue without getting interrupted?

Comment: Is it event possible?